# Is there a technical term for a 'complementing' number that sums to 1?

Tags: terminology

I'm looking for a technical name (if one exists) for a number that 'completes' or 'complements' another. The motivation for this is to develop a proper understanding of mathematical language, for example in naming variables while programming.

Say if I have a value x = 1/26. Is there a name for y = 25/26 that fills in the remaining part of the fraction?

In essence, if I have some x, I want a technical name for the value of y = (1-x).

Comment: difference maybe?

Answer (score 1):

[Complementary event](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementary_event) probability, but it's a rather long name for a variable.

Comment: If $x$ were the probability of an event then $1-x$ would be the *probability of* the complementary event, not the complementary event itself. I'm not convinced a widespread snappy name for $1-x$ (in terms of $x$) exists, especially not outside of probability theory.

Comment: @CliveNewstead: Thank you for pointing that out (added "probability" to the answer).